# Unix script to archive logs - execute all command even one fails

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

**Objective :** Unix script should archive Logs older than 2 days.

**Issue :** If there are no files when it is archiving or moving file still whole script should be executed.

**Script File Content :** archivelogs.sh

```
find /logs/tomcat/*.* -type f -name "*.*" -mtime +2 -print -exec gzip {} \;
find /logs/tomcat/*.gz -exec mv -f '{}' /logs/tomcat/logsbkp/ \;
find /logs/jboss/*.* -type f -name "*.*" -mtime +2 -print -exec gzip {} \;
find /logs/jboss/*.gz -exec mv -f '{}' /logs/tomcat/logsbkp/ \;
```

**Solution:** 
Kindly suggest how can i maksure all commands executed even if above command failed.

**Note:** 
My crontab will run the job every day at 12:00 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest while adding these commands to crontab, please capture the output of above commands in log file. And then grep error or some string from log files to get errors , and if there is error in the log files use mailx to send the error in mail. create a crontab job to do this and schedule it after all your archive jobs are completed.

Comment: This is a good option and i added a script in crontab which will find n days old files and archive them.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be adding this line in your script.

```
#!/bin/sh +e
```

or

```
set +e
```

you can reverse it using

```
set -e
```

## set -e option

> Exit immediately if a pipeline , which may consist of a single simple command , a list ,
>   or a compound command  returns a non-zero
>   status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of
>   the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part
>   of the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a &&
>   or || list except the command following the final && or ||, any
>   command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return status
>   is being inverted with !. If a compound command other than a subshell
>   returns a non-zero status because a command failed while -e was being
>   ignored, the shell does not exit. A trap on ERR, if set, is executed
>   before the shell exits.
>
> This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately , and may
>   cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the
>   subshell.
>
> If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the
>   compound command or function body will be affected by the -e setting,
>   even if -e is set and a command returns a failure status. If a
>   compound command or shell function sets -e while executing in a
>   context where -e is ignored, that setting will not have any effect
>   until the compound command or the command containing the function call
>   completes.